# Python sort dictionary using key

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python sort dictionary. I want to sort the below dictionary using **name** key.

I try this but not working.

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

**Sample dictionary**

```
[
        {
            'id': 34, 
            'pid': 7, 
            'name': '1.1. Data Foo', 
            'open': 'open',
            'children' : [
                {
                    'id': 23,
                    'pid': 89,
                    'name': '1.1.1. Data 4',
                    'open': 'open'
                },
                {
                    'id': 23,
                    'pid': 89,
                    'name': '1.1.4. Data 6',
                    'open': 'open'
                },
                {
                    'id': 23,
                    'pid': 89,
                    'name': '1.1.2. Data 14',
                    'open': 'open'
                },
            ]
        }, 
        {
            'id': 32, 
            'pid': 7, 
            'name': '1.3. Data Bar',
            'open': 'open',
            'children' : [
                {
                    'id': 23,
                    'pid': 89,
                    'name': '1.2.1. Data 14',
                    'open': 'open'
                },
                {
                    'id': 23,
                    'pid': 89,
                    'name': '1.4.4. Data 86',
                    'open': 'open'
                },
                {
                    'id': 23,
                    'pid': 89,
                    'name': '1.0.2. Data 114',
                    'open': 'open'
                },
            ]
        }, 
        {
            'id': 33, 
            'pid': 7, 
            'name': '1.2. Data Rex'
             'open': 'open',
            'children' : [
                {
                    'id': 23,
                    'pid': 89,
                    'name': '2.1.1. Data 4o0',
                    'open': 'open'
                },
                {
                    'id': 23,
                    'pid': 89,
                    'name': '14.1.4. Data 676',
                    'open': 'open'
                },
                {
                    'id': 23,
                    'pid': 89,
                    'name': '1.11.2. Data 1423',
                    'open': 'open'
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
```

Comment: That's not a dictionary. That's a list (of dictionaries). It's quite different. Do you want to sort a list based on values of the dicts inside it?

Comment: @MilesDavis yes I want to sort  alphabetically using name key

Comment: there are multiple `name` keys. do you mean the ones that are on the same level as `pid`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to sort by the `name` in the first level of each item in the list, the following one-liner will sort it.

```
a_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
```

Comment: it returns None

Comment: It sorts in place.

Comment: yes just as your code

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand your last comment.

Comment: I try your code without changing

Comment: Try `print(a_list)` after the above line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213164/discussion-between-c-grey-and-srikant).